# AlwaysOnTop conflict

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener, always-on-top

I have two Java applications running.
One is the mother system and another is a sub application. Both using JFrame. 
Both has an alwaysOnTop(True) behaviors. I have no access on the mother system and it is overriding the alwaysonTop behavior of my sub application.

I tend to invoke requestFocus() on method calls. 
That seems to suffice in most cases but when idle or start up,
the sub application sometimes dont get the focus.

How do I override the mother application's always on top when I do not have access to the mother application?

I also did this

```
addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
        requestFocus();

    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {

    }
```

Comment: This is OS specific behavior, but you could try using `toFront`

Comment: Iterate the [available windows](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#getWindows--) find the one that you refer to as 'mother' and call `setAlwaysOnTop(false)` on it.  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: @andrewThompson i do not have access to the mother app code.

Comment: Is while(isVisible){ toFront() } good?

Comment: *"i do not have access to the mother app code."* You don't need access to the code of `MotherFrame` to do what I suggested.  Are you saying the two frames do not run in the same JVM?

Comment: *"Is while(isVisible){ toFront() } good?"*  I'd describe that is an 'ugly hack' and in no way 'good'.  It would seem to block the EDT.

Comment: *"Is while(isVisible){ toFront() } good?"*  Tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.